# program window becomes white when unfolded from the tray

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyside6, tray

[image]

with two activated checkboxes autostart and start minimized the program becomes white when unfolding from the tray, help to fix the problem, because autostart works, but start minimized does not work, also tell me how to fix the fact that when closing the program it continues to work, here is the program code

```
import configparser
import ctypes
import os
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, QThread, Signal
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QHeaderView,
    QCheckBox,
    QSystemTrayIcon,
    QMenu,
    QFileDialog,
    QMessageBox,
)

from qdarkstyle import load_stylesheet_pyside6
from screeninfo import get_monitors

class CheckboxUpdateThread(QThread):
    checkbox_states_updated = Signal()

    def run(self):
        while not self.isInterruptionRequested():
            self.checkbox_states_updated.emit()
            self.msleep(1000)

class WallpaperTimeApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("WallpaperTime")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1280, 720)

        # Change the current working directory
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

        self.checkboxes = []

        # Tray setup
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.tray_menu = QMenu(self)
        self.tray_action_show = self.tray_menu.addAction("Show")
        self.tray_action_exit = self.tray_menu.addAction("Exit")
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(self.tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

        # Load settings from file
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.load_settings()

        # Start the checkbox update thread
        self.checkbox_update_thread = CheckboxUpdateThread(self)
        self.checkbox_update_thread.checkbox_states_updated.connect(self.load_settings)
        self.checkbox_update_thread.start()

        # Tray icon click event
        self.tray_icon.activated.connect(self.handle_tray_icon_activated)

        # Timer to update wallpaper
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_wallpaper)

        # Initialize intervals
        self.intervals = []
        self.load_intervals()

        # UI setup
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.interval_table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.interval_table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.interval_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["Start Time", "End Time", "Wallpaper Path"]
        )
        self.interval_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.interval_table.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        self.update_interval_table()

        self.start_time_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.end_time_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.wallpaper_path_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.wallpaper_path_button = QPushButton("Select Wallpaper", self)
        self.wallpaper_path_button.clicked.connect(self.select_wallpaper)

        self.add_button = QPushButton("Add", self)
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_interval)

        self.edit_button = QPushButton("Edit", self)
        self.edit_button.clicked.connect(self.edit_interval)

        self.delete_button = QPushButton("Delete", self)
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_interval)

        self.autostart_checkbox = QCheckBox("Autostart", self)
        self.autostart_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.toggle_autostart)
        self.checkboxes.append(self.autostart_checkbox)

        self.start_minimized_checkbox = QCheckBox("Start Minimized", self)
        self.start_minimized_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.toggle_start_minimized)
        self.checkboxes.append(self.start_minimized_checkbox)

        self.minimize_button = QPushButton("Minimize", self)
        self.minimize_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_minimize_button_clicked)
        self.minimize_button.setEnabled(True)

        # Status label for visualization
        self.status_label = QLabel(self)
        self.status_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Rename the method to avoid conflict
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.interval_table)

        form_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        form_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Start Time:"))
        form_layout.addWidget(self.start_time_input)
        form_layout.addWidget(QLabel("End Time:"))
        form_layout.addWidget(self.end_time_input)
        form_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Wallpaper Path:"))
        form_layout.addWidget(self.wallpaper_path_input)
        form_layout.addWidget(self.wallpaper_path_button)

        self.main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)

        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(self.add_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.edit_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.delete_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.autostart_checkbox)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.start_minimized_checkbox)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.minimize_button)

        self.main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.status_label)

        # Set the style sheet
        self.setStyleSheet(load_stylesheet_pyside6())

        # Show the window
        self.show()

    def update_checkbox_states(self):
        for checkbox in self.checkboxes:
            checkbox_name = checkbox.text().replace(" ", "").lower()
            if self.config.has_option("General", checkbox_name):
                checkbox_state = self.config.getboolean("General", checkbox_name)
                checkbox.setChecked(checkbox_state)

    def update_interval_table(self):
        self.interval_table.clearContents()
        self.interval_table.setRowCount(0)
        for i, (start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path) in enumerate(self.intervals):
            self.interval_table.insertRow(i)
            self.interval_table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(start_time))
            self.interval_table.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(end_time))
            self.interval_table.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(wallpaper_path))

    def load_settings(self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("settings.ini")

        if config.has_section("Intervals"):
            self.intervals = []
            for key, value in config.items("Intervals"):
                start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path = value.split(",")
                self.intervals.append((start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path))

        if config.has_section("General"):
            for checkbox in self.checkboxes:
                checkbox_name = checkbox.text().replace(" ", "").lower()
                if config.has_option("General", checkbox_name):
                    checkbox_state = config.getboolean("General", checkbox_name)
                    checkbox.setChecked(checkbox_state)
                    checkbox.update()  # Update the checkbox display

    def save_settings(self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()

        if not config.has_section("Intervals"):
            config.add_section("Intervals")
        for i, (start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path) in enumerate(self.intervals):
            config.set(
                "Intervals", f"interval{i}", f"{start_time},{end_time},{wallpaper_path}"
            )

        if not config.has_section("General"):
            config.add_section("General")
        for checkbox in self.checkboxes:
            checkbox_name = checkbox.text().replace(" ", "").lower()
            config.set("General", checkbox_name, str(checkbox.isChecked()))

        with open("settings.ini", "w") as config_file:
            config.write(config_file)

    def load_intervals(self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("settings.ini")

        if config.has_section("Intervals"):
            self.intervals = []
            for key in config["Intervals"]:
                start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path = config["Intervals"][key].split(
                    ","
                )
                self.intervals.append((start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path))

    def handle_tray_icon_activated(self, reason):
        if reason == QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.showNormal()  # Use showNormal() to restore the window
            self.tray_icon.hide()

    def handle_minimize_button_clicked(self):
        self.hide()
        self.tray_icon.show()

    def add_interval(self):
        start_time = self.start_time_input.text()
        end_time = self.end_time_input.text()
        wallpaper_path = self.wallpaper_path_input.text()

        if not start_time or not end_time or not wallpaper_path:
            QMessageBox.critical(
                self, "Error", "Please fill in all fields before adding an interval."
            )
            return

        if not self.validate_time_format(start_time) or not self.validate_time_format(
            end_time
        ):
            QMessageBox.critical(
                self, "Error", "Invalid time format. Please use HH:MM format."
            )
            return

        self.intervals.append((start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path))
        self.update_interval_table()
        self.save_settings()

    def validate_time_format(self, time_str):
        try:
            datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M")
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def edit_interval(self):
        selected_row = self.interval_table.currentRow()
        if selected_row != -1:
            start_time = self.start_time_input.text()
            end_time = self.end_time_input.text()
            wallpaper_path = self.wallpaper_path_input.text()

            if not start_time or not end_time or not wallpaper_path:
                QMessageBox.critical(
                    self,
                    "Error",
                    "Please fill in all fields before editing the interval.",
                )
                return

            if not self.validate_time_format(
                start_time
            ) or not self.validate_time_format(end_time):
                QMessageBox.critical(
                    self, "Error", "Invalid time format. Please use HH:MM format."
                )
                return

            self.intervals[selected_row] = (start_time, end_time, wallpaper_path)
            self.update_interval_table()
            self.save_settings()

    def delete_interval(self):
        selected_row = self.interval_table.currentRow()
        if selected_row != -1:
            del self.intervals[selected_row]
            self.update_interval_table()
            self.save_settings()

    def toggle_start_minimized(self):
        start_minimized = self.start_minimized_checkbox.isChecked()  # noqa: F841
        self.save_settings()  # Move the save_settings() call here

    def create_autostart_entry(self):
        script_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        key_path = r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
        key_name = "WallpaperTime"
        value = f'"{script_path}"'

        try:
            subprocess.run(
            ["reg", "add", key_path, "/v", key_name, "/d", value, "/f"], check=True
            )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("Error creating autostart entry:", e)

    def remove_autostart_entry(self):
        key_path = r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
        key_name = "WallpaperTime"

        try:
            subprocess.run(
                ["reg", "delete", key_path, "/v", key_name, "/f"], check=True
            )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("Error removing autostart entry:", e)

    def toggle_autostart(self):
        autostart_enabled = self.autostart_checkbox.isChecked()
        if autostart_enabled:
            self.create_autostart_entry()
            if self.start_minimized_checkbox.isChecked():
                self.handle_minimize_button_clicked()
        else:
            self.remove_autostart_entry()
        self.save_settings()  # Save settings after creating/removing autostart entry

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.tray_icon.hide()
        # Start the timer when the application is shown
        self.timer.start(6000)

        # Check if started from autostart and should be minimized
        autostart_enabled = self.autostart_checkbox.isChecked()
        start_minimized = self.start_minimized_checkbox.isChecked()
    
        if autostart_enabled and start_minimized:
            self.hide()
            self.tray_icon.show()
        else:
            self.showNormal()

    def is_between_times(self, current_time, start_time, end_time):
        if start_time <= end_time:
            return start_time <= current_time <= end_time
        else:
            return current_time >= start_time or current_time <= end_time

    def update_wallpaper(self):
        current_time = datetime.now().time()
        wallpaper_path = None

        for start_time, end_time, path in self.intervals:
            start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M").time()
            end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%H:%M").time()

            if self.is_between_times(current_time, start_time, end_time):
                wallpaper_path = path
                break

        if wallpaper_path:
            try:
                self.set_wallpaper(wallpaper_path)
                self.status_label.setText(f"Wallpaper updated at {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")
            except Exception as e:
                self.status_label.setText(f"Error updating wallpaper: {e}")
        else:
            self.status_label.setText("No wallpaper set for the current time.")
            return

        # Convert the wallpaper path to a format compatible with SystemParametersInfo function
        wallpaper_path = os.path.abspath(path)

        # Set the wallpaper
        SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(
            SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, wallpaper_path, 3
        )

    def set_wallpaper(self, path):
        # Check if the file exists
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            self.status_label.setText(f"Error: The wallpaper file '{path}' does not exist.")
            return

        # Convert the wallpaper path to a format compatible with SystemParametersInfo function
        wallpaper_path = os.path.abspath(path)

        # Set the wallpaper for all monitors
        SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
        for monitor in get_monitors():
            ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(
                SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, wallpaper_path, 3
            )

    def select_wallpaper(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Select Wallpaper",
            "",
            "Images (*.jpg *.png *.jpeg);;All Files (*)",
            options=options,
        )
        if file_path:
            self.wallpaper_path_input.setText(file_path)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.tray_icon.hide()
        self.timer.stop()
        self.save_settings()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow::title { background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120); }")
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    if not os.path.exists("icon.png"):
        print(
            "The icon.png file is missing. Please place it in the same directory as the script."
        )
        sys.exit(1)

    window = WallpaperTimeApp()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I've tried many ways, but all of them either fail or make the program window invisible

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre], as your code includes lots of parts that are completely irrelevant to the question. On a separate note, it makes absolutely no sense to use a thread just to call a function at repeated intervals (use QTimer), and it's also quite pointless to continuously read the configuration every second.

Comment: You're hiding the window while it's being shown, which is clearly wrong. If you want to prevent showing on startup, just do *not call* `self.show()` in the `__init__` in case the settings tell so. Remove the whole `showEvent()` implementation as it's pointless, other than wrong: you are already hiding the icon in `handle_tray_icon_activated`, and the timer should certainly not start only when the window is shown. Still, keep in mind everything suggested above. Note that the `QMainWindow::title` stylesheet is useless, as the window title is drawn by the OS and not controlled by Qt.